# Xml dtd file Iso8583 acceptable or not

Tags: xml, dtd, iso8583

I have to send an isoMessage 8583 in c#. I constructed the XML file like below

Do not pay attention the length of the fields, I just want to know if this is acceptable?

**This is my xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Iso8583PostXml SYSTEM "genericpackager.dtd">
<isopackager>
   <MsgType>0200</MsgType>
   <isofield>
      <Field_2>5555555555555555</Field_2>
      <Field_3>01</Field_3>
      <Field_4>0001</Field_4>
      <Field_5>11223344</Field_5>
      <Field_6>000000000001</Field_6>
      <Field_7>000000000000</Field_7>
      <Field_8>0792</Field_8>
      <Field_9>0000000000</Field_9>
      <Field_10>0949</Field_10>
      <Field_11>170101</Field_11>
      <Field_12>00</Field_12>
      <Field_13>3800</Field_13>
      <Field_14>0110A080002A3400CAE200000000000000FF</Field_14>
      <Field_15>0000000000000000</Field_15>
      <Field_16>00</Field_16>
      <Field_17>3030</Field_17>
   </isofield>
</isopackager>
```

and my xml dtd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ELEMENT isopackager (isofield+,isofieldpackager*,MsgType)*>
<!ELEMENT MsgType (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST isopackager maxValidField     CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isopackager bitmapField       CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isopackager thirdBitmapField  CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isopackager firstField        CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isopackager emitBitmap        (true|false) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isopackager headerLength      CDATA        #IMPLIED>

<!-- isofield -->
<!ELEMENT isofield (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST isofield id     CDATA        #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofield length CDATA        #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofield name   CDATA        #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofield class  NMTOKEN      #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofield token  CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isofield pad    (true|false) #IMPLIED>

<!-- isofieldpackager -->
<!ELEMENT isofieldpackager (isofield+,isofieldpackager*)*>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager id       CDATA        #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager name     CDATA        #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager length   CDATA        #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager class    NMTOKEN      #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager token    CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager pad      (true|false) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager packager NMTOKEN      #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager emitBitmap (true|false) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager maxValidField CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager bitmapField CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager firstField  CDATA        #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST isofieldpackager headerLength  CDATA        #IMPLIED>
```

I will send the xml formatted file  related to dtd file. I am not sure if it is a correct way to communicate with this type of xml

Comment: this is the reason you downvoted instead of warning

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: @kjhughes I edited my question. According to a document(postbridge specification which is used by banks) I will have to use this kind of xml format

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's "acceptable" or not will depend on the acceptance criteria; those depend on what you have engaged to provide your recipient and not on the XML spec, so your main question cannot be answered here.  I guess, however, that you mean "Does this DTD conform to the XML spec, is this XML instance valid against this DTD, do both of them together conform to ISO 8583, and have I violated some widely followed community conventions in the way I've done things?"

You can check yourself whether the DTD conforms and whether the XML is valid against it, by saving your files somewhere and running an XML validator over them.  (If you don't know how to do this or don't know what I mean, then by undertaking to provide an XML-encoded message you may have bitten off more than you can chew.)  I don't see any syntax errors in the DTD file, but I'm not a machine checker and I have not checked your DTD with an XML parser. (I'd get rid of the XML declaration in your DTD file, but I'm not sure it's an error to have it.)

The DTD does not, however, describe your XML.  It declares element types named isopackager, MsgType, isofield, and isofieldpackager; the last does not appear in your XML.  Your XML includes elements named Field_2, Field_3, etc., which are not declared in your DTD.  The declaration for isofield says that valid instances of that element type contain character data, and only character data, but the isofield element in your XML contains a sequence of elements named Field_2, Field_3, etc.  There may be other discrepancies; machines are much better at reporting them than humans.

A quick glance at the Wikipedia article on ISO 8583 makes no mention of a standardized XML syntax, so I have no idea whether your XML format satisfies any syntactic constraints imposed by such a format if it exists.  Since I don't know 8583 at all, I have no opinion on whether your format is a correct representation of ISO 8583 semantics.

As for community conventions, the only recommendations I'd make would be to have more explanatory comments in your DTD.  (I don't much like working with elements named Field_2 and Field_3, but I have to say I like that much better than working with elements tagged `<Field fieldnum="2" ...` and `... fieldnum="3" ...`, so I won't complain.)

It's not clear exactly what you're looking for (which I assume is part of why some people want to close the question); I hope this helps a bit. Good luck.